# PHP move_uploaded_file() deosn't work

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload file to my Raspberry Pi 3. I installed Apache and PHP and this is the content of the page index.php:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>

<?php
if ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] != 0 && $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] != "")
{
    $uploaddir = "/var/www/html/";
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
    try 
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile))
        {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "File upload failed\n\n";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage()."\n"; }

    echo "Array content:\n";
    print_r($_FILES);

    print "</pre>";
} ?>
```

When I upload a file, even a text file with some bytes in it, move_uploaded_file() returns false and the file is not uploaded, however no exception is thrown and the value of `$_FILES["userfile"]["error"]` is 0. The permission of the folder `/var/www/html/` are `drwxr-xr-x`, so they should be enough, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was enough to run `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/`. I was quite sure that I did that already but probably I didn't do it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the directory create function.. I Believe you forgot to create a directory on the name u need.. and u need the permission to upload a file u requested.. Try this and tell me the results.. And if possible create a inner directory to ease ur prob.. else change the directory permission using [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) .. Thanks and regards

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>

<?php
if ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] != 0 && $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] != "")
{
    $uploaddir = "./html/"; // i changed it to relative pathname, it will be easy if u r uploading this code to server or so
    if (!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
        mkdir($uploaddir, 0777);
    }
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
    try 
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile))
        {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "File upload failed\n\n";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) { 
        echo $e->getMessage()."\n"; 
    }

    echo "Array content:\n";
    print_r($_FILES);


    print "</pre>";
} ?>
```

Before trying the code try setting the permission of the directory, try this in ur terminal..

```
>sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html
```

im using ubuntu and its working for ubuntu...

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't even create the directory and mkdir() doesn't throw any exception. Maybe apache doesn't have the permission but it seems strange, I launch it with `sudo systemctl start apache2.service`, maybe I should launch it in another way?

Comment: Check out the permission bro.. Probably you r missing them.

Comment: What permission do I need to check in particular?